# Program that chose the method to use based on the argument's suffix of the input files

Tags: java, serialization

How can we implement a general program that takes an argument but based on the suffix of the input files (.csv or .ser) it chooses which mechanism to use to read the data.

Thank you,

Comment: so you are taking file as an input am i right ? and then based on the extension of file you are calling methods ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extension of a file and then based on the extension of your file, you can call your desired methods. You can use [FilenameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) from apache. Here is a sample program

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
class FileExtension{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("//path//to//your//file");
        if(ext1.equals("csv")){
            //call csv function to read data
        }else if(ext1.equals("ser")){
            //call ser function to read data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but then I need to download apache classes? is there a way without apache ?

Comment: You can reinvent the wheel